# Finding bad systemctl definitions?

Tags: systemd

I've just had to diagnose a fault that turned out to be because someone had edited a systemd definition (*.service) file and left an error behind.  The result was that the service did not show up as failed but also did not run so my question is:

> Is there a way to list all systemd units that have service definition errors?

As an example, here is the status of the job that failed:

```
localhost:~# systemctl status -l custom
● custom.service - Custom script
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/custom.service; disabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 12 16:00:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: 
[/usr/lib/systemd/system/custom.service:20] Unknown section 'Path'. Ignoring.
```

I've tried listing `dead` services but there are many of them and most seem to be correct but just ended - what I want is to find the ones that have genuine errors such as this one.

Comment: `systemd-analyze verify ...` will do some checks. see `man systemd-analyze`.

Comment: It is a little verbose but that's certainly good enough for what I want - thanks.

Comment: I am turning @meuh ’s answer into an answer, because, well, it is one.

Answer (score 2):

`systemd-analyze verify …` will do some checks.

see `man systemd-analyze` for options.